# ruby on rails find_or_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any better way to achieve this in Ruby on Rails?

I'm searching for 11 fields and all are required also, and if not found initialize it.

There will be more required fields adding to it.

This query works perfect for me, but it just doesn't look like the best way to do this.

```
find_or_initialize_by_make_and_country_and_engine_and_power_and_body_and_doors_and_fuel_and_cylinders_and_transmission_and_gears_and_wheels(model,country,engine,power,body, doors, fuel, cylinders, transmission,gears,wheels)
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

On rails 3.2 I would do

```
attributes = {}
Model.where(attributes).first_or_initialize
```

Documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize

Comment: This should be the excepted answer.

Comment: Agreed with @jahrichie. Added bonus is that this syntax is still correct as of Rails 4.2.

Comment: @stringsn88keys , @Filipe Giusti: Can we use `ILIKE` in `where` with `first_or_initialize` in `Rails 3`. Something like: `User.where("name ILIKE ?", myname).first_or_initialize` OR use ruby's `downcase`?

Comment: In our code, we've tended to prefer a forced `downcase`, so that it works with indexes in Postgres. I'm not sure if other databases have indexing strategies that work better with case insensitivity. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-types.html

Comment: @AtulKhanduri I don't think Rails can handle "Pure String Conditions" on initialize.

Comment: @jahrichie except that it should be accepted. I am expecting that you will get my point ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Considering the sheer number of fields you are using, you probably are better off manually finding the record and initializing it if it does not exist:

```
attributes = {
  country: country,
  engine: engine,
  power: power,
  body: body
  etc ...
}

record = where(attributes).first
record = new(attributes) unless record
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define method like this in your model

```
def self.find_or_initialize_by_field(params)
    send("find_or_initialize_by_#{params.keys.join("_and_")}", *params.values)
end
```

and then you can call this method like

```
YourModel.find_or_initialize_by_field({country: country, engine: engine})
```

Answer (score -2):

while using `find_or_intialize_by`

find by key fields , dont assign all the feilds at once

eg I assume the make is the key field in the model

```
car = find_or_initialize_by_make(model)

car.update_attributes(country: country,engine: engine,power: power, body: body,doors: doors ,fuel: fuel,cylinders:cylinders,transmission: transmission, gears: gears, wheels: wheels)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Dynamic+attribute-based+finders

Comment: Thanks for reply. It will be good while initialization but when I search  only for Model during find I'll get multiple records back.(In my case it will be huge)

Comment: there will be some combination that will yeild a unique record right, use that key in find_or_initialize the key fields are mostly your primary and foreign keys , or combination of both.

Comment: @jahrichie that is 3 years old answer and was valid then now it as changed as per rails version upgrade to 4

Comment: This answer won't work, you can't call update attributes on a new, unsaved record.